# Answer panel sorting when a question gains multiple answers

Tags: bug, answers, sorting, live-refresh

I had a question open that had zero answers. While it was open, two people answered it. The familiar popup of "2 new answers to this question" appeared, I clicked it, and:

1. The sorting box (active - oldest - votes) did not appear
2. The answers were not sorted by any immediately obvious order.

Obviously, this is a pretty rare bug (multiple answers, answers must get votes, all while the page is sitting open?) that fixes itself by a simple page reload, but I thought I should mention it here. This occurred in Chrome Version 41.0.2272.118 m.

Screenshot:

[image: Bug Screenshot]

Comment: May not be so rare - if you asked then left overnight or while at work.